# How to introduce new stream format in beanio

Tags: bean-io

Is beanio can support more stream format other than csv, fixedLength, delimited, json and xml? I have created a new module from beanio to add new format, But the beanio.properties used by StreamCompiler to map the format is resides in the beanio parent project, how will I add a new format to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you can extend BeanIO this way, but it would be great if this works for you.

See [Section 8](http://beanio.org/2.1/docs/reference/index.html#Configuration) of the reference documentation on how to provide your custom `beanio.properties` file

> 8.0. Configuration
>
> In some cases, BeanIO behavior can be controlled by setting optional property values. Properties can be set using System properties or a property file. BeanIO will load configuration setting in the following order of priority:
>
> - System properties.
> - A property file named `beanio.properties`. The file will be looked for first in the application's working directory, and then on the classpath.
>
> The name and location of `beanio.properties` can be overridden using the System property `org.beanio.configuration`. In the following example, configuration settings will be loaded from the file named `config/settings.properties`, first relative to the application's working directory, and if not found, then from the root of the application's classpath.
>
> `java -Dorg.beanio.configuration=config/settings.properties example.Main`

Please let us know if you can extend the formats supported this way.

Comment: Yes it is working now. I am able to add new format now.

Comment: @AVM Could you please accept my answer as correct if it was the solution to your problem? Otherwise, please show us in an answer what you have done. Thx